# Button that scroll down goes slow and then accelerate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

It's just suppose to scroll down, but in the process it start slow for less than a second an then accelerate to the speed that i chose.

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('html').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#div12').offset().top
    },800);
});
```

Someone knows why that happend?

I looked for the definition of the fuinctions i used to see if something there could help me, but nothing.

Comment: *to the speed that i chose* - you don't choose a *speed*, you specify a *duration*.  Whether it does easing, linear, or some fancy bounce, it will still take 800ms.